# Removing data frame rows outside a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, tuples

Say I have this tuple:

```
    [('1975-01-02', '1975-01-03'),
     ('1975-01-05', '1975-01-06')]
```

I want to edit that tuple based on this data frame:

```
DATE        HH    MM   SS   DOY    DST
1955-01-01   0     0   0.0    1    -20
1955-01-02   1     0   0.0    2    -60
1955-01-03   2     0   0.0    3    -70
1955-01-04   3     0   0.0    4    -50
1955-01-05   4     0   0.0    5    -40
1955-01-06   5     0   0.0    6    -80
```

If DST<-50, in the particular tuple, then that tuple must be removed.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Before we can help, please include a minimum reproducible code, and show us what you have tried so far to solve your own problem.

Comment: what @Arsik36 says: Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a good  pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and revise your question accordingly , [Please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @Arsik36 I am new to python. I hope I could have show you some code.

Comment: @anky If I had done coding then I could have posted it.

Comment: @AyushiNema I have linked you to the links that would help you create a dummy problem, I am assuming you know a little about pandas.. if not, please invest some time in documentation and some basic tutorials to get started.

Comment: @anky Hoping for the solution. Thanks for those tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

**Your dataframe with DST**

```
>>> a =pd.DataFrame({'DST':[33,11,2,-67,-80],'Date':['1975-01-03','1975-01-06','1975-01-07','1975-01-07','1975-01-15']})
>>> a
   DST        Date
0   33  1975-01-03
1   11  1975-01-06
2    2  1975-01-07
3  -67  1975-01-07
4  -80  1975-01-15
```

**Your tupels**

```
>>> t = [('1975-01-03', '1975-01-06'),('1975-01-13', '1975-01-15'),('1975-01-31', '1975-02-02'),('1975-02-03', '1975-02-13'),('1975-03-09', '1975-03-14'),('1975-03-14', '1975-03-16'),('1975-03-26', '1975-03-29'),('1975-04-8', '1975-04-13'),('1975-04-22', '1975-04-24'),('1975-05-4', '1975-05-07')]
```

**Now filter out all the elements where DST is more than -50**

```
>>> keep = a[a['DST'] < -50]
>>> keep
   DST        Date
3  -67  1975-01-07
4  -80  1975-01-15
```

**Iterating throw all the valid dates and checking if they exist in the range of the tuple**

```
>>> for i in keep['Date']:
        final = []
        final = final + [j for j in t if i>=j[0] and i<=j[1]]
```

**Final list with tuples**

```
>>> final
[('1975-01-13', '1975-01-15')]
```

Please use code for dataframes like this post so that the ones solving your problem does not need to generate their own.

Comment: Hi Frans, thanks for you precious comment. People like you helps a lot to newcomers. I tried your logic in my real data. But I got final result as tuple of last year date i.e., of 2018. So i kept empty list final[] outside the for loop. Now I am getting tuple of same values.